# Reading Java servlet bytes from stream on C# client

Tags: java, c#, stream

I'm having issues reading in bytes sent by a Java servlet to a client written in C#.

**C# Code**

```
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://path.to/servlet");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "text/html";

            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream respStream = res.GetResponseStream();
            byte[] re = new byte[512];
            respStream.Read(re, 0, re.Length);
            MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Default.GetString(re));
```

**Java Code**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    ServletOutputStream resp = response.getOutputStream();
    try{
        resp.write(new String("Test String").getBytes());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I realize that there are differences between Java bytes, and C# bytes (signed vs unsigned), but I have no clue how to stream java's signed bytes into something that c# can recognize. Any ideas? Do I need to tweak something on the servlet as far as how I send the information, or does the C# bit need to be modified?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use the underlying bytes, instead of using text encoded in UTF-8 (or UTF-16)? I suggest you look at [`ServletResponse.getWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29) (It's probably a good idea to also [`ServletResponse.flushBuffer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#flushBuffer%28%29)).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch tried the getWriter() option, and received the same characters, I also tried using a TextReader, after the writer was used in the servlet, and ended up with the same thing. Is there anything different that I should do in the C# code that would let me better read the response from a java printwriter?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest thing to do is in your C# code specify the encoding, instead of

```
Encoding.Default.GetString(re)
```

You should be able to use,

```
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(re)
```

According to the Wikipedia entry on [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) it is a superset of ISO-8859-1 (the Java default character encoding). You might consider explicitly using UTF-8 on both sides,

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(re)
```

and in Java,

```
new String("Test String").getBytes("UTF-8")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only getting two of the black diamond question mark symbols (when using UTF-8), or two ASCII symbols (when using 1252).